# Realm one to many relationship not persisted

Tags: android, database, realm, persistence, one-to-many

I'm trying to implement a `Many-to-many relationship` with `Realm` between `User`and `Chat` objects. I'm following [the oficial documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships). Here are my objects.

```
 public class User implements RealmModel {

  @PrimaryKey
  private String userId;
  private String name;
  private String phone;
  private String pictureURL;
  private String thumbnailURL;
  private String pushToken;
  private String status;
  private long lastOnlineMs;
  public RealmList<Chat> chats = new RealmList<>();

  public User() {}

}  

public class Chat implements RealmModel {

  @Required
  @PrimaryKey
  private String chatId;
  private long creationDateMs;
  private String creatorUserId;
  private String name;

  @LinkingObjects("chats")
  public final RealmResults<User> users = null;

  private int chatType;


  public Chat() {}
 }
```

Here is the code where I create the `Chat` object in the database and add the relation. The users have been correctly created before:

```
public void addChat(final Chat chat, final User creatorUser, final User opponentUser ) {
    realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chat);

        creatorUser.chats.add(chat);
        opponentUser.chats.add(chat);
    });
}
```

After executing the code `User` and `Chat` objects are stored in database but `chat list` for users are empty.

I also use `realm.beginTransaction` that is just a same like `executeTransaction`, the difference just execute are thread safe.

I also use `realm.insertOrUpdate(obj)`, but just have same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyToRealmOrUpdate` from doc :

> Updates an existing RealmObject that is identified by the same {@link io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey} or a new copy if no existing object could be found

It does not update the RealmObject your are giving as parameter because it's not a managed object yet, so you need to retrieve the returned object that is managed to add it to your users.

```java
public void addChat(final Chat chat, final User creatorUser, final User opponentUser ) {
    realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        Chat managedChat = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(chat);
        creatorUser.chats.add(managedChat);
        opponentUser.chats.add(managedChat);
    });
}
```